# World's decision to switch to LED lighting (to save $) cause more health problems? Migraines? Circadian-Rhythm? Seizures? Light-sensitivity?

Tags: triggers, circadian-rythym, light-sensitivity, migraine-auras, led-lights

I have not switched to LED lighting in my home (though I know that it saves a lot of money in the long run) because I know how it personally impacts me. Not only does it **disrupt my circadian-rhythm** (and as an insomniac -- it makes it that much harder to sleep --- it's like taking an alcoholic into a bar), but I find that I have a lot of **sensitivity to the light**, which often trigger some of my migraines with a **migraine aura**. Once that migraine get's triggered, it's all downhill from there.... so I try to minimize the impact of LED lights in my home as much as possible.

However, no matter what I or others do, the world is quickly jumping on the LED bandwagon (it makes economic sense -- I don't blame them), but I'm wondering if anyone **has considered how LED lighting will negatively impact societies' health?**

For instance, now that cars have LED headlights, I find it really difficult to drive at night as my eyes are super sensitive to the brightness of the lights and I wince.... *Not only does it trigger a migraine, but it could potentially cause me to have an accident if my eyes are closed.*

**Are LED lights known to cause seizures?**

**What kind of research has been done, if any, to see how the switch to LED lights will negatively impact the human health?**

Comment: I can understand the question as there are anecdotal reports of fluorescent lighting and fluorescent based energy saving lighting causing migraines due to hard to detect flickering.  I think the question needs splitting into migraine issues, circadian rhythm issues, light sensitivity issues etc. separately as the question is broad whilst having all issues in one question.

Comment: @Chris Sidenote: Unfiltered (for a lack of proper vocab atm) "neon" tubes and bulbs, flickering with the net freq of 50 or 60Hz, are terrible *and easy to detect*. Just wiggle a pen and see the strobe effect come to life. With LEDs any issues that there are are quite different.